# Radzen Validation in a ForEach

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have a Foreach which contains a RadzenNumeric and Validation for it.  The issue I am having is that the Name and Component are the same for every item in the Foreach.  So if 1 out of 10 have a value then they all do not show the validation error.

Question is, what is the best approach to make the name Unique?  Is there a way to do a Counter within the Foreach and just add that value to the end of the Name and Componenet?

```
@foreach (Models.Ingredients.MeasuredIngredient measuredIngredient in CompoundIngredient.MeasuredIngredients)
{
    <div class="ingredient-seperator"></div>
    <div class="row ingredient">
        <div class="amountInput col-6 col-md-2">
            <RadzenNumeric class="newInput" Name="Amount" @bind-Value="measuredIngredient.Amount" TValue="decimal" Min="0"></RadzenNumeric>
            <RadzenRequiredValidator class="rz-message rz-messages-error rz-message-popup newInputValidation" Component="Amount" Text="Amount is required" DefaultValue="0" Popup="true" />
        </div>
        
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to number them.

```
@{ var index = 0; }

@foreach (Models.Ingredients.MeasuredIngredient measuredIngredient in CompoundIngredient.MeasuredIngredients)
{
    index += 1;
    <RadzenNumeric class="newInput" Name="@("Amount"+index)" @bind-Value="measuredIngredient.Amount" TValue="decimal" Min="0"></RadzenNumeric>
    <RadzenRequiredValidator class="rz-message ..." Component="@("Amount"+index)" Text="Amount is required" ... />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with Radzen Name and Component is that it does not support Complex Types.  Based on Henk Holtermans suggestion here would be how to get it working

```
@{
   int i = 0;
   string amount = "Amount" + i.ToString();
   string type = "Type" + i.ToString();
   string ingredient = "Ingredient" + i.ToString();
}
@foreach (Models.Ingredients.MeasuredIngredient measuredIngredient in CompoundIngredient.MeasuredIngredients)
{
    <div class="ingredient-seperator"></div>
    <div class="row ingredient">
         <div class="amountInput col-6 col-md-2">
               <RadzenNumeric class="newInput" Name="@(amount)" @bind-Value="measuredIngredient.Amount" TValue="decimal" Min="0"></RadzenNumeric>
               <RadzenRequiredValidator class="rz-message rz-messages-error rz-message-popup newInputValidation" Component="@(amount)" Text="Amount is required" DefaultValue="0" Popup="true" />
         </div>
    </div>

   i++;
   amount = "Amount" + i.ToString();
   type = "Type" + i.ToString();
   ingredient = "Ingredient" + i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you _need_ the `amount` variable?  Or is that just a style?  Because `="@("Amount"+index)"`  ought to 'just work'.

Comment: Yes in normal razor syntax that would work.  The issue is Radzen doesnt allow for Complex Types within the Name so @("Amount" + index) causes an exception.  So you need to set the variable before declaring it in the name

Comment: What do you mean by Complex Types ?  I just did `<RadzenTextBox Name="@("test"+2)"` and that worked fine.

Comment: Test + 2 works but Test + variable doesnt.

Comment: No repro again: `<RadzenTextBox Name="@("test"+ x++)"` is fine. Not that it matters a lot but I'd like to be clear for future visitors of this page.  It's not a Radzen thing.

Comment: The quotes-inside-quotes syntax can be a bit intimidating, use `='@("test"+ x++)'` if you like. And when that doesn't work, post exact error messages.

Comment: and now i cannot repo it as well.   Your way does work correctly